# Understanding IIS vs Service

Tags: web-services, iis, service

What is the difference between a web service deployed through IIS and a simple windows service that just responds to http requests?

Do IIS web services get compiled to a binary executable as a regular windows service would?

What files/settings does IIS require to define a web application?

What aspects of a web application are handled by IIS which would have to be reimplemented when creating a windows service that responds to http requests?

Answer (score 0):

IIS provides a hosting environment with,

- Application pools
- Standard extension API
- Other IIS only features.

You can search other materials comparing self hosting and hosting on IIS to learn more.